# Success not getting called on data returned by web-service in ajax call vb.net

Tags: json, ajax, vb.net, web-services

I  am using ajax to call a web-service in vb.net.My web-service is getting called successfully but after returning data control goes directly to OnError of ajax call.Also web-service is getting called successfully but after that control goes directly to failure method.My ajax call is like this:

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Transactions/WBS_Budget_Dynamic.aspx/GetAllData",
            dataType: "text",
            async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
                alert("Local error callback.");
            },

            success: function (data) {

                 alert(JSON.stringify(data.d));
                            :
                            :
```

My webservice returing data  like this:

```
  dttask = objProjectBL.GetBudgetProcessDetails(ProjNo, Parent, Type, Level, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, UserNm, HostNm, SelectType, Report_id)
            Dim serializer As System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim rows As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object)) = New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()


            Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
            For Each dr As DataRow In dttask.Rows

                row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
                For Each col As DataColumn In dttask.Columns

                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))

                Next
                row.Add("ParentId", Parent)

                Dim str As String = dr("Tree_id").ToString()
                Dim count As Integer = str.Split(".").Length - 1
                Dim LevelCount As Integer = count - 1

                row.Add("LevelId", LevelCount.ToString())
                rows.Add(row)
            Next



            Return serializer.Serialize(rows)
```

Comment: This post is too long. Can you shorten it to attract more readers?

Comment: And format your code better.  And the tag should be VB not C#